# Realm 0.92.1 won't build with Carthage

Tags: ios, realm

I started a new Swift project and wanted to try out Realm. Right now my cartfile only has this:

```
github "realm/realm-cocoa"
```

When I run carthage update the first time I got the following output:

```
*** Fetching realm-cocoa
*** Downloading realm-cocoa at "v0.92.1"
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “Realm.framework” doesn’t exist." 
UserInfo=0x7ffdb87739d0 {NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/carthage-archive.khSkep/Carthage/Build/iOS/RealmSwift.framework/Frameworks/Realm.framework, NSUserStringVariant=(
Copy
),
NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/username/Documents/Projects/projName/Carthage/Build/iOS/Realm.framework, NSFilePath=/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/carthage-archive.khSkep/Carthage/Build/iOS/RealmSwift.framework/Frameworks/Realm.framework, NSUnderlyingError=0x7ffdb8762d50 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}
```

then I run carthage update again and get this:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “RLMRealm_Private.h” doesn’t exist." 
UserInfo=0x7fe9eac45e70 {NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/carthage-archive.h1rPWy/Carthage/Build/iOS/Realm.framework/PrivateHeaders/RLMRealm_Private.h, NSUserStringVariant=(
Copy
), 
NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/username/Documents/Projects/projName/Carthage/Build/iOS/Realm.framework/PrivateHeaders/RLMRealm_Private.h,
NSFilePath=/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/carthage-archive.h1rPWy/Carthage/Build/iOS/Realm.framework/PrivateHeaders/RLMRealm_Private.h, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe9eac46690 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}
```

Seems like the first time I carthage update the missing Realm.Framework gets added, but the second time it can't get past the missing RLMRealm_Private.h

anyone else seen this yet?

Comment: I tried again this morning, and now carthage thinks I'm missing different files. This time around carthage said that "Resources" doesn't exist, then moved on to "strip-frameworks.sh" doesn't exist the next couple times

Comment: The problem is that Carthage doesn't currently support frameworks containing other frameworks, which is the case for Realm. There's an open pull request to add that functionality to Carthage, which has yet to be reviewed: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/pull/446.

Comment: @jpsim I see that pull request 446 was accepted, but I'm still getting the same problems. I'm on carthage 0.6.3 and it's pulling realm 0.92.2. this is the error I get: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “strip-frameworks.sh” doesn’t exist." UserInfo=0x7fae54a01b30 {NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/private/var/folders/wq/jn7tswgj6_93y4l1b83r9xrdky6mzb/T/carthage-archive.kBtcDe/Carthage/Build/iOS/RealmSwift.framework/Frameworks/Realm.framework/strip-frameworks.sh, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Copy
)

Comment: You'll have to use Carthage 0.7.2 or later, which contains that pull request

Comment: Yeah, I went to 7.2 shortly after that comment and it's still hanging on "Fetching realm-cocoa". Looks like 7.3 was supposed to get pushed to homebrew this morning but there were some issues. I'll try again later today

Comment: Yes, that's a known issue with Carthage 0.7.0-0.7.2. 0.7.3 is already released, but the homebrew PR is still pending: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/39677

Comment: @jpsim I got carthage 0.7.3 this morning and tried to carthage update again, but it's still hanging while trying to fetch repos. Weird

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. The issue is being tracked in Carthage's GitHub issues here: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/455